# populating data from a join

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Although I know a bit of SQL, I have never really used relational databases before, as I realise this is a powerful thing I'm trying to learn how to do it in PostgreSQL. I currently have a three database tables I'm trying to connect, they are as follows:

```
comics:  
  id(int)
  issue(int)  
  series(varchar[255])  
  publisher(int)  
  type(int)

publishers:  
  id(int)
  name(varchar[255])
  url(varchar[255])

type:
  id(int)
  name(varchar[255])
```

In each table the ID is the primary key and there is an fkey constrain on comics.publisher (to publishers.id) and comics.type (to type.id)

I have the following query string:

```
'SELECT * FROM comics JOIN publishers ON (publisher = publishers.id) JOIN comic_types ON (type = comic_types.id);'
```

Which sort of works but it doesn't do what I expected, what I was hoping was to get back the following result:

```
id: 1,
issue: 1,
series: 'Civil War',
publisher: 'Marvel',
type: 'single issue'
```

However what I got was:

```
id: 1,
issue, 1,
series: 'Civil War',
publisher: 1,
type: 1,
name: 'Single issue',
url: 'marvel.com'
```

If I have to namespace my entries then so be it but surely there is a way to pull the publishers.name into comics.publisher and type.name into comics.type?

If so can someone please tell me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you use table aliases and qualify all column names.  You should list the columns that you want in the `SELECT` to be sure there are no naming collisions.  Something like this:

```
SELECT c.*, p.name as publisher_name, ct.name as type_name
FROM comics c JOIN
     publishers p
     ON c.publisher = p.id JOIN
     comic_types ct
     ON c.type = ct.id;
```

Comment: Wow, I love how terse that is! Plus I still get to use the * selector! Thanks this works really nicely.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be having collisions between identical column names. Explicitly specify the columns you are interested in.

```
'SELECT comics.id, comics.issue, comics.series, publishers.name as publisher, type.name as type FROM comics JOIN publishers ON (publisher = publishers.id) JOIN comic_types ON (type = comic_types.id);'
```

Comment: Perfect! I guess I was just being lazy trying to get everything! :) Thank you.